# How can I move a list item from one list to another?

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile and once I click on a link from this list:

```
<div id="scroller">
    <div class="trans">
        <ul id="thelist" data-corners= "false" data-role="listview">
             <div class = "theListItem" data-role="collapsible-set" data-collapsed="false">
                 <li><a class= "left" data-inset="true" data-transition="pop" href="YesNoMaybe.html"><h4>Think Coffee</h4><h3>$3.50</h3></a></li>
                 <li><a class= "left" data-inset="true" data-transition="pop" href="YesNoMaybe.html"><h4>Think Coffeadsf dsadsf ads faf adsf adsf adsf sadf asdf adsfadsfadsfadsfadsf sadfasdfe</h4><h3>$3.50</h3></a></li>
                 <li><a class= "left" data-inset="true" data-transition="pop" href="YesNoMaybe.html"><h4>sup Coffee</h4><h3>$3.50</h3></a></li>
             </div>
         </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would love if the `<h4>` and `<h3>` text replaced the text on this list:

```
<ul id="thelist" data-corners= "false" data-role="listview">
    <div class = "theListItem" data-role="collapsible-set" data-collapsed="false">
        <li class="purchase" ><a data-inset="true"  href="#"><h4>Think Coffee</h4><h3>$3.50</h3></a></li>               
    </div>
</ul>
```

I tried this:

```
$('#transPage').live('pageinit', function() {
$('a').click(function(){
    var $move = $(this).closest('li').appendTo("#YesNoMaybePage .theListItem");
  });
});
```

And got nowhere.  The lists are on different pages.  All advice is more than welcome.   Thanks world.  I owe u bigtime.

Comment: You'll have to remove it from the DOM first; so something like `...closest('li').remove().appendTo...`

Comment: and use .on instead of .live

Comment: `$('#transPage')` or `$('#trans')`?

Comment: It's `#transPage`.  The whole page is wrapped in that ID.  U can ignore the `.trans` on the list.  That's something else.  Thanks guys.

Comment: If he doesn't want to `remove()` the DOM object, he could `clone()` it. Why do you have `var $move` but don't use it.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that too.  How should I use that `$move`?

Comment: You shouldn't. At least not in this case. `.appendTo(...)` returns jQuery, I'd expect that to be the html after it has been appended (I assume, doc it not clear). Sometimes it can be needed, not in this case.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what it is you want. You say you only what the <H> tags replaced but in the code you add the entire list item. Which is it?

Comment: I suppose I only want the <H> tags replaced, but I would like to see anything actually happen :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along these lines.

```
$('#transPage').on('pageinit', function() {
  $('a').click(function(){
    var $h4 = $(this).find('h4').text(); // select the text of h4
    $('.purchase h4').text($h4);         // insert the text in the target

    var $h3 = $(this).find('h3').text();
    $('.purchase h3').text($h3);
  });
});
```

I tested it on jsFiddle and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/3JWFJ/

Comment: Thank you!  This works great.  My only issue, is that it only works when I refresh the second page, `#YesNoMaybePage`, and not when I refresh `#transPage`.  Any idea why?

Comment: With the code snippets given, I can't say that I do. Sorry. You can try using console.log() or alert() to see if the scripts trigger as expected.